# If the defined period of my probation extention has passed without it being further extended, is it complete?

Tags: probation

I had my probation period extend by a month to the 1st of September. This has passed, my boss called Friday and asked for a 'chat' today. Although we were both in the office for the whole day we didn't chat.

He has now asked to meeting away from the office on Wednesday. As the 1st of September has come and gone, have I technically passed my probation period?

During in the time I've have only had two meetings with my boss, one approximately after 3 months and then one the day after my 6 month probation period finish (my probation finished on a Sunday).

I have had very little training and little to no guidance. Although my performance has not hit the targets in terms of sales and meetings I don't believe I was given a sufficient base to reach these targets. In addition I have achieved sales that are only slightly less than my counterpart in half the time.

If they dismiss me, should it be for the notice period of my probation (1 month) or that of having passed it (3 months)?

Comment: I would get those cvs out

Comment: `He has now asked to meeting away from the office on Wednesday.` I guess you find out on Wednesday.

Comment: voting to close - company specific regulations.   Only your boss can really answer these

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/47564/in-uk-can-a-company-extend-the-probation-period-after-it-ended/47578#47578 depending on jurisdiction...

Comment: Answering this depends on whether your probation period is a legal concept in your jurisdiction (as is the case in much of Europe), making it a (trivial) legal question. If it's not then it all depends on company policy which [as mentioned](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/54055/if-the-defined-period-of-my-probation-extention-has-passed-without-it-being-furt#comment137578_54055) is also off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

**Depends on the country laws** I totally agree with what [Julia](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/54065/27375) said and want just to add something to it:

In my country the law says, that to pass a probation, you just do not get fired during the probation. So if time of probation passes without being fired, you technically passed a probation and are full time employee now.

But, I support the idea: Do not leave anything critical in the office, you might get barred from office access. But, you can consult with the lawyer and maybe fight back.

But, honestly, if the worst happens, I would rather seek for job elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

You may have *completed* the probation period but you haven't passed or failed until he formally notifies you to that effect. If he's asking to meet out of the office, then it's a big red flag that he doesn't want you being physically in the office after he's said his piece. Prepare for the worst - and if I were you I wouldn't leave anything critical in the office on Tuesday night; it sounds like you will get your belongings returned at some vague future time, not be allowed to collect them.

Comment: He may be looking to take you out for a celebratory lunch! Don't assume the worst, just be prepared for it.